# extracting 800 and 600 from 800x600

Tags: c++

I have ComboBox which contain values for resolution. Starting from 800x600 to 1920x1080. I was trying to extact (this)x(and this) from resolution modes. I am able to get selected value from ComboBox but i fail to what i planed with string i get.

```
        comboBox->GetSelectedValue() // i get value here
        std::stringstream buffer;
        buffer << comboBoxValue;
        std::string myBufferResolution = buffer.str();
        size_t Position1 = 0;
        size_t Position2;

        Position2 = myBufferResolution.find("x", Position1);
        myBufferResolution.substr(Position1, (Position2-Position1));
        Position1 = Position2+1;

        std::cout << "Selected resolution is: " << myBufferResolution << std::endl;
```

std::cout only prints selected value but what i wanted, which i would get if i cout comboBox->GetSelectedValue().

How to get values from 800x600, 1024x768 etc etc? since i am doing something wrong

Comment: You really should define variables at the point where you initialize them: `size_t Position2 = myBufferResolution.find( ... `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`string::substr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method *returns* a newly allocated string, it doesn't modify the object you're calling it on.

So, it should be e.g.:

```
const std::string width = myBufferResolution.substr(Position1,
                                                    (Position2-Position1));
```

I do think there are better ways to do this (in C I would use `sscanf(myBufferResolution.c_str(), "%ux%u", &width, &height);`).

Comment: +1 for `sscanf`. I'd use that even in C++, because the stringstream alternatives are just too stupidly cumbersome. And a decent compiler will protect you from the obvious pitfalls, anyway.

Comment: The `sscanf` is a sure route to unmaintainable code.  Why `"%u"`, for example?  What happens if the actual type of `width` and `height` is `short`?  Or is changed from `int` to `short` at some later date?

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, I realize `sscanf()` is not loved in C++. In C, compilers check the format string to match it against the arguments, so it's not that bad. And `%u` in my world since the resolution is a count value, and thus cannot be negative.

Comment: @unwind It shouldn't be unsigned, since they are numeric (arithmetic) values, and something like `abs(h1 - h2)`, for example, makes sense (but gives the wrong results with unsigned types).

Comment: @JamesKanze Hm ... so when *would* you use an unsigned, then?

Comment: @unwind Most obviously, in the rare cases when I want modulo arithmetic (calculating a hash code, for example).  In general, it's also a sign that some bitwise operations going to be involved.  And finally, there's no problem with using it for non-arithmetic things like serial numbers (except that it's unusual, so readers may ask).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use regular expressions, but it's
probably overkill for this; something like:

```
std::string::const_iterator pivot
        = std::find(resolution.begin(), resolution.end(), 'x');
if (pivot == resolution.end()) {
    //  Error handling, string did not have expected format...
}
std::string width( resolution.begin(), pivot );
std::string height( pivot + 1, resolution.end() );
```

if you want the two values as strings,

```
std::istringstream s(resolution);
int width;
int height;
char separ;
s >> width >> separ >> height;
if ( !s || s.get() != EOF || separ != 'x' ) {
    //  Error handling, string did not have expected format...
}
```

if you want them as numeric values.